# Setting pandas boxplot y-limit dynamically

Tags: python, pandas, boxplot

I am forming a bunch of boxplots like so:

```
for name, data in test_imp_groups:
    data = data[data['impressions'] > 500]
    if len(data['impressions']) > 0:
        quantile = data['impressions'].quantile(.98)
        print quantile
        print name
        ax = data.boxplot(column="impressions", by="month", figsize=(15,10), whis=[5, 95])
        ax.set_ylim(0, (quantile))
        plt.show()
```

I am setting the y-limit dynamically by taking the 98th quantile.  If my whiskers end at the 95th quantile, how come some of my graph whiskers reach outside of the plot like this?:

[image]

Comment: Try this: initialize `quantile=1e-20`, then in the for loop `quantile=max([data['impression'].quatile(98),quantile])` and just set the ylim one time after the loop and then `plt.show()`

Comment: why don't you take `max()` as the upper limit?